# Calculating the percentage of currency

Tags: percentages

Let's say you want to send money with through my agency.

I will get 0.05 on every dollar.

That is if you send \$100 dollars, should get 0.05 on each of the dollars in the \$100.

I am doing this $100 \times 0.05 = 5$.

How can I apply this to other currencies like Euro, or Australian dollar for example? Let say you decide to send money using Euro or other currency?

Comment: Dollars are just a unit.  They don't play any role in the problem–you could just as easily work with Euro or Rubles or whatever.  On the other hand, if you are asking about first buying dollars with some other currency, then this isn't a question about mathematics, but a question about economics(?) or something.

Comment: This does not look like a math problem at all.  Perhaps you want to charge $5\%$ on each transaction, perhaps the fee you charge varies with the currency, why not?  You might not have all currencies on hand and if you have to make an exchange your fee should reflect the cost of that exchange.  In any case, it's not a math question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the exact same thing. If you take five cents out of every dollar, then you also take five (euro-)cent out of every euro, and five pennies out of every pound. You take $5\%$ (i.e. multiply by $0.05$, as you did above) of anything sent through your agency, regardless of what currency is used.